# What is the difference between '&' and ',' in Java generics?

Tags: java, generics

While reading the Java official tutorial about generics, I found that you can restrict the type argument (in this case is `T`) to extend a class and/or more interfaces with the 'and' operator (`&`) like this:

```
<T extends MyClass & Serializable>
```

I replaced the `&` with `,` (by mistake and still works, with a minor warning).

My question is, is there any difference between these two:

```
<T extends MyClass & Serializable>
<T extends MyClass , Serializable> // here is with comma
```

And the example method:

```
static <T extends MyClass & Serializable> ArrayList<T> fromArrayToCollection(T[] a) {
    ArrayList<T> arr = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (T o : a) {
        arr.add(o); // Correct
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: @Doorknob you are assuming the OP is using a keyboard and the same keyboard as you are using.

Comment: @emory I think even that is wrong the direction - the error wasn't in his fingers but in his brain. Similarly to as if you'd tried to use 'include' instead of 'import' in a Java source file. You mistyped 'include', because your brain told you to type the wrong thing, which is possible for various reasons.

Comment: @Nicholas Pickering, is right! For me, it was not a mistype because of the keyboard, but because of the brain. When you write which interfaces a class implements, you separate them by comma.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

```
<T extends MyClass & Serializable>
```

This asserts that the single type parameter `T` must extend `MyClass` and must be `Serializable`.

```
<T extends MyClass , Serializable>
```

*This* declares *two* type parameters, one called `T` (which must extend `MyClass`) and one called `Serializable` (which hides `java.io.Serializable` — this is probably what the warning was about).